# How mongodb will be indexed when column has single and array value?

Tags: mongodb

How will be indexed in mongodb when column has single value as well array value?

Example:

```
{ _id: 1,
   exchange: 'US'},
{ _id: 2,
   exchange: ['US','UK']}
```

if we create index in mongodb on column exchange, how will it be created?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indexed using multi key indexes, where each array element is a key in index.

Please see [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/) for more details. So even if another document has a non array value for this attribute, it creates no problem as it is just another entry in the index with a single key. But if there are two elements ['US','UK'] as value of exchange, then that makes two entries in the index for exchange.